# Why is Capistrano failing deploy with Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4, nginx, capistrano

I have setup a Capistrano deploy in my site and I am trying to deploy to a staging server. The server is a CentoOS 6 server with nginx and passenger running through with it.

Everything runs okay except I get this error when I do 'cap staging deploy':

```
rake aborted!
DEBUG [3489dd68]    PG::ConnectionBad: FATAL:  Ident authentication failed for user "postgres"
```

In my /var/lib/pgsql/data/pg_hba.conf I have got the following setup:

```
# TYPE  DATABASE    USER        CIDR-ADDRESS          METHOD

# "local" is for Unix domain socket connections only
local   all         all                               ident
local   all         postgres                          md5
local   all         popup                             md5
local   all         root                              md5
# IPv4 local connections:
host    all         all         127.0.0.1/32          ident
# IPv6 local connections:
host    all         all         ::1/128               ident
```

Then in my config/database.yml file I have got this:

```
development:
  adapter: sqlite3
  database: db/development.sqlite3
  pool: 5
  timeout: 5000

staging:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: popuphub_staging
  username: postgres
  password: r00t2xtry
  host: localhost

production:
  adapter: postgresql
  database: popup_production
  username: forge
  password: 7PoXsewpEiR8xcTityaecZczUWxAag
  host: localhost
```

I have looked at the deploy.rb file and everything is working fine.

```
lock '3.1.0'
server "0.0.0.0"

set :application, "PopupHub"
set :scm, "git"
set :repo_url, "git@another-repo-url-here.git"
# set :scm_passphrase, ""

# set :user, "deploy"

# files we want symlinking to specific entries in shared.
set :linked_files, %w{config/database.yml}

# dirs we want symlinking to shared
set :linked_dirs, %w{bin log tmp/pids tmp/cache tmp/sockets vendor/bundle public/system}

SSHKit.config.command_map[:rake]  = "bundle exec rake"
SSHKit.config.command_map[:rails] = "bundle exec rails"

#default_environment["RAILS_ENV"] = 'current'

set :branch, ENV["REVISION"] || ENV["BRANCH_NAME"] || "master"


set :keep_releases, 20

namespace :deploy do
  desc 'Restart passenger without service interruption (keep requests in a queue while restarting)'
  task :restart do
    on roles(:app) do
      execute :touch, release_path.join('tmp/restart.txt')

      unless execute :curl, '-s -k --location localhost | grep "Pop" > /dev/null'
        exit 1
      end
    end
  end
  after :finishing, "deploy:cleanup"
  after :finishing, "deploy:sitemap:refresh"
end

after "deploy", "deploy:migrate"
after 'deploy:publishing', 'deploy:restart'
```

I am guessing its a deeper issue with postgresql in the root server but I am struggling to figure it out.

I think I need a little direction with this.

Comment: Have you found a solution to this?